# How can I create a custom outlook email column that is set to a value found in the body of an email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016

[image: Outlook Custom Column]

How can I setup an email custom column in outlook that is set to the value of a string that occurs in the body of an email?

I've tried setting the formula of the column to:

```
InStr(1,[Message],"ProductId",1)
```

Which would work in combination with other outlook column forumulas to find the string (which is always the same length) except the `Message` column only contains a truncated message of the original email and so often the string occurs too far into the email to catch it.

Is there a way to access the full text of the email to find the product id string or another technique I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this help:   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-columns-in-the-inbox-78098e3e-8203-47da-815e-cb66f76b512e#:~:text=To%20create%20a%20custom%20column,name%2C%20and%20then%20click%20Remove.

Comment: That's how I've added the column, but I can't figure out how to set the value of it or create a column formula that shows the value, I was working on using InStr as Outlook column formulas seem to support a subset of VBA functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function

Comment: I hope this can help you: https://www.slipstick.com/tutorial/create-a-custom-field-to-mark-messages/#:~:text=To%20create%20a%20custom%20field%3A%201%20Open%20the,mark%20an%20item.%207%20Return%20to%20Outlook.%20%E6%9B%B4%E5%A4%9A%E9%A1%B9%E7%9B%AE